# Windows 11 and Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9 dual boot not working with GRUB

Tags: grub, windows-11, redhat-enterprise-linux, bootloader, dualboot

I have problems with RHEL 9 and Windows 11 in GRUB.

I added `menuentry "Windows 11" {set root=(sda1) chainloader +1}` to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` and then executed the command `grub2-mkconfig --output=/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`, the Windows 11 shows in the GRUB menu but the error below comes.
Windows 11 efi partition is in sda1.

The GRUB menu will show up in startup when pushing shift at startup, but when I select RHEL or Windows 11 it shows error message: `error ../../grub-core/net/net.c:1394:no server is specified` and `error ../../grub-core/loader/i386/pc/linux.c:422:you need to load the kernel first.`

Windows 11 has been installed with GUID partition table and I am using UEFI mode.
I have installed RHEL 9 with GPT and MBR, but always the same result.
I think whole of operating systems must be use the same partition type, in this situation GPT.

Windows 11 fast boot is disabled.
Windows 11 is in drive sda and RHEL 9 in drive sdb, so the operating systems are in separate drives.

So, anyone know how can I dual boot the RHEL 9 and Windows 11 with GRUB ?

Answer (score 1):

> I have installed RHEL 9 with GPT and MBR

This is not going to work.

Windows 11 must have UEFI (so GPT), Secure Boot, and TPMV2.  MBR cannot be used.

Make a Virtual Machine for RedHat and that will work perfectly well.

VMWare is the best and most flexible VM App.  Virtual Box works and Hyper-V works (although I do not know if Hyper-V supports RedHat - it likely does) .

Comment: I agree with you, I think RHEL 9 and Windows 11 must use the same partition tables.
In this situation Windows and RHEL must use GPT that the dual boot is possible.
MBR for RHEL was only experiment, because I did not get the dual boot to work.

I want physical RHEL server, no virtual machine.
So, that's why I want dual boot Windows 11 and RHEL 9.
I think the dual boot is possible some way, but I do not know why it is not working.

Comment: You may need to try a different server OS that is more compliant with Windows 11.  You might also want to see if a bare metal hyperviser might work for you

Comment: I could try the bare metal hypervisor if no one knows how to dual boot RHEL 9 and Windows 11.